# Update MYSQL with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to build a mobile application with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile . In my app I have a page where is a link to PHP file which updates MYSQL and heads to next page. But with PhoneGap I need to have all the PHP files on external server so I can't my current solution on this application.

This is the PHP that I use to update MYSQL

```
<?php

$var = @$_GET['id'] ;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE table SET condition=true
WHERE ID= \"$var\" ");

header('Location: http://1.2.3.4/test');

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

So how can I run this PHP when user clicks a button? With jQuery/AJAX i suppose?

Comment: can you send some code where you call this php page in apps.

Comment: This is prone to `SQL` injection. Never insert user-provided data directly into a query without escaping them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets say the above PHP code is in file, update.php. Then you can use the following code -

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function UpdateRecord(id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update.php",
       data: 'id='+id,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
       }
     });
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button_id" value="Update" onClick="UpdateRecord(1);">
</body>
```

Just pass a valid id in the UpdateRecord function. Put your PHP code in update.php file. Just to be on a safer side, in your PHP code replace `$var = @$_GET['id'] ;` with `$var = @$_POST['id'] ;` and check if this works for you

Comment: whatever id you are passing, you need to make sure it points to a valid record in database. Also make sure 'jquery.js' is present in your folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function UpdateRecord(id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: 'id='+id,     // <-- put on top
       url: "update.php",
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
       }
     });
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button_id" value="Update" onClick="UpdateRecord(1);">
</body>
```

Those codes suggested by **Sachyn Kosare** does work, the only thing is that the line `data: 'id='+id` has to be on top of `url: "update.php"`

And, you can use `$var = $_POST['id'];` for your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

say your button has an id `clickme` you bind an event handler on it as follows, I am usnig the on selector to avoid cases where the code is executed when the button does not exist on the page.. you can very well bind a `click` handler

```
$(document).on("click","#clickme",function(){
    $.ajax({

        type:"POST", //GET - update query should be POST
        url: my_endpoint.php,  //your php end point
        data: {jsonKey1:jsonValue1},
        success: function(data){ //if success
          //do necessary things with data
        }

    })
});
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Do something in your success function

```
success: function(response)
   {
       window.location = response;
   }
```

and you html should contain

And in php do something like this

```
mysql_query('blah blah');
mysql_close($con);

echo "http://1.2.3.4/test";
```